# SQL.swift select from multiple tables

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I use [SQL.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) but I cannot find a way to select values from multiple tables during a join. My db structure is the following:

```
airport --* tower --* tower_frequency
```

An airport can have several control towers and each control tower can have several radio frequencies. Given an airport `ident`, I want to select all radio frequencies.

I build the query using

```
let airportTable = Table("airport")
let uid = Expression<Double>("id")
let ident = Expression<String>("ident")

let towerTable = Table("tower")
let frequencyTable = Table("tower_frequency")

var query = airportTable
    .select(airportTable[*], towerTable[*], frequencyTable[*])
    .join(towerTable, on: airportTable[uid] == towerTable[fkAirportId])
    .join(frequencyTable, on: towerTable[uid] == frequencyTable[fkTowerId])
    .filter(airportTable[ident] == icao)
```

The generated SQL is from `query.asSQL()` is

```
SELECT "airport".*, "tower".*, "tower_frequency".* FROM "airport" 
INNER JOIN "tower" ON ("airport"."id" = "tower"."fk_airport_id") 
INNER JOIN "tower_frequency" 
ON ("tower"."id" = "tower_frequency"."fk_tower_id") 
WHERE ("airport"."ident" = 'SBP')
```

and it works fine when I run it manually in the db, yet `SQL.swift` throws the exception `No such table: "tower"`

Comment: SQL.swift is probably right.  But without a description of your schema, it's hard to tell what's wrong.   Perhaps your tower table is called "Tower".  And if you really want the frequencies, you'll have to select them too.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my sample code. I do select * from all the three tables and as I wrote, running the same SQL in the db directly works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this happens when I use the star query `frequencyTable[*]` on the second on third table. When I use an explicit query it works
: `.select(airportTable.table[*], frequenciesTable.table[frequencyCol])`

I'll open a bug in the project